# How to turn off auto completion for property brackets?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, properties, autocomplete

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. This line:

```
public static List<BaseRecipe> Recipes { get { return recipes; } }
```

turns into the below when I'm typing it out.

```
public static List<BaseRecipe> Recipes
{
    get
    {
        return recipes;
    }
}
```

And yes, I do have "Automatic brace completion" turned off in "Options > Text Editor > C#". It's not a huge deal, just a small annoying issue that takes ten or so seconds to fix every time I type out a property.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off `Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting > General > Automatically format block on }`